# Back/Forward fill DataFrameGroup by based on column condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am conducting a back and forward fill on a column on a DataFrame based on an ID.

Attempted solution:

```
def my_func(x):
    if merged['email_conf'].isnull().all():
        return x.bfill().ffill()
    else:
        return merged['email_conf'].bfill().ffill()

merged['email_unconf'] = merged.groupby('id')['email_unconf'].apply(my_func)
```

There are some instances where the each id has more than one email for example. I have a third column called `email_conf` and if within the `group by` that column contains an email, I use that one to back and forward fill (if it appears in `email_conf` the email will also be present in `email_unconf`. Otherwise I just use the `email_unconf` column to b/f fill.

Starting dataframe:

```
            id          email_unconf      email_conf
    5827553206045509    unc1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    unc1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com   conf1@gmail.com
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    unc1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045509    NaN               NaN
    .
    . 
    .
    5827553206045510    unc2@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045510    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045510    NaN               NaN
    5827553206045510    NaN               NaN
    .
    .
    .
```

Resulting Df:

```
            vid         email_unconf      email_conf
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com   conf1@gmail.com
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045509    conf1@gmail.com    NaN
    .
    . 
    .
    5827553206045510    unc2@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045510    unc2@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045510    unc2@gmail.com    NaN
    5827553206045510    unc2@gmail.com    NaN
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: so whats the question/issue?

Comment: I want to back/forward fill `email_unconf` with the email contained in that column. However, if an email exists in the `email_conf` column, prioritize that email for the f/b fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dictionary to map the values from the `'email_conf'`, then forward fill and back fill the rest.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


cols = ['id','email_unconf','email_conf']
data = [
    ['5827553206045509',    'unc1@gmail.com',    np.nan],
    ['5827553206045509',    'unc1@gmail.com',    np.nan],
    ['5827553206045509',    np.nan,               np.nan],
    ['5827553206045509',    np.nan,              np.nan],
    ['5827553206045509',    'conf1@gmail.com',   'conf1@gmail.com'],
    ['5827553206045509',    np.nan,               np.nan],
    ['5827553206045509',    np.nan,                np.nan],
    ['5827553206045509',    np.nan,               np.nan],
    ['5827553206045509',    np.nan,                np.nan],
    ['5827553206045509',    np.nan,              np.nan],
    ['5827553206045509',    'unc1@gmail.com',    np.nan],
    ['5827553206045509',    np.nan,               np.nan],
    ['5827553206045509',    np.nan,                np.nan],
    ['5827553206045509',    np.nan,               np.nan],
    ['5827553206045510',    np.nan,    np.nan],
    ['5827553206045510',    'unc2@gmail.com',                np.nan],
    ['5827553206045510',    np.nan,               np.nan],
    ['5827553206045510',    np.nan,               np.nan]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

not_null = df[~df['email_conf'].isna()]
email_dict = dict(zip(list(not_null['id']), list(not_null['email_conf'])))

df['email_unconf_fill'] = df['id'].map(email_dict).fillna(df['email_unconf'])
df['email_unconf_fill'] = df.groupby('id')['email_unconf_fill'].ffill()
df['email_unconf_fill'] = df.groupby('id')['email_unconf_fill'].bfill()


df['email_unconf'] = df['email_unconf_fill']
df = df.drop('email_unconf_fill', axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
                  id     email_unconf       email_conf
0   5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
1   5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
2   5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
3   5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
4   5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com  conf1@gmail.com
5   5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
6   5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
7   5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
8   5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
9   5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
10  5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
11  5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
12  5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
13  5827553206045509  conf1@gmail.com              NaN
14  5827553206045510   unc2@gmail.com              NaN
15  5827553206045510   unc2@gmail.com              NaN
16  5827553206045510   unc2@gmail.com              NaN
17  5827553206045510   unc2@gmail.com              NaN
```